# Classification criteria in MapStruct Mapper design?

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm looking for the right design pattern.

When implementing Mapper using Mapstruct, is it correct to create a new Mapper for each DTO (or Entity)?

Suppose I have a UserInfoDTO and I have a UesrCountDTO.

The business logic is completely different, but they all start with a UserEntity .

If so, isn't it wrong to implement two Entity To DTO functions after creating a UserMapper class for these two?

or

UserInfoMapper,
Is it the right design to separate each with a UserCountMapper class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MapStruct generates the implementation for you, I think you should not be concerned with the design of the generated code, but with that of your own code, where you are going to use these methods.

If both mappings are meant to be used in a single object, you should put them in the same mapper interface, so you will only have to inject one mapper.

On the contrary, if these methods are not related, and one should not be mislead, or tempted to use them in the wrong place, then you should separate them, to enforce their purpose.